# How to get the total sum of a column in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

i have a two columns in jqgrid, ShopID and NetSales, and i would like to add `Contribution Column` which will be a calculated column. the formula is NetSales divided by Total. please see image for example.[image]

i know how to get the Total using `getCol` like this `var sumtotal = grid.jqGrid('getCol', 'NetSales', false, 'sum');`, but dont know how to use it further for division. i have tried, but it didnt work. please help.

i

Comment: Which `datatype` have the grid? I'd recommend you don't use calculated column. It's very easy to calculate the sum directly having the data. Having the sum you can fill the data for Contribution column based on the sum and NetSales from the column.

Comment: @Oleg, I have local datatype sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commonly you have two ways to solve the problem

1. As mentioned into the note you should calculate the sum of the column before to put the data into the grid. If you have this value you can use a custom fomatter to calculate the percentage. In this case the calculated sum should be defined as global in the scope.
2. Direct calculation of this without using any jqGrid method - see below

Suppose you have a local data like this

```
mydata = [ 
   {ShipId: 1, NetSales: 150000},
   {ShipId: 2, NetSales: 200000},
   ...
]
```

You can easy do (no checks it is just idea)

```
var sum  = 0;
$.each(mydata, function( i, row) {
    sum += parseFloat(row.NetSales);
}
$.each(mydata, function( i, row) {
    if (sum > 0 ) {
        row.Contribution = parseFloat(row.NetSales)/sum*100;
    }
}
```

Then put mydata in jqGrid directly without to do any calculation and use custom formatter to display the percentage.

Comment: thank you so much sir, I’m trying this method now, will update shortly.

Comment: i have applied the second method sir as per your example, and it is working.thank you.